# Where are sources of the direct inspect api sets in xenserver?

Tags: virtualization, xen

As we all know, xenserver is a industry-leading open source virtualization platform and there's a feature called Direct Inspect API sets in XenServer 7 Enterprise Edition. Where is the source code of this Direct Inspect API sets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** and **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39782498/edit) the post to add relevant code in the question.

Comment: We are here to help you solve your issues. Rather then completely answering and writing code for you. Please let us us know what efforts have you put to do this.